# Can nerds own dogs?

Tags: constructor-hd

When dealing with the AI, I end up putting dogs everywhere to avoid the micromanagement of stopping takeovers and fixing the fence afterwards. Unfortunately, Nerds complain about one of the following:

- Not having a picket fence
- Having a dog and an insecure fence (which a picket fence is)

I had a similar problem with Students until I found they also like the Brick Hedge. Is there a secure equivalent of a picket fence?

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?